# Show Posts feature in a blog

Tags: mongodb, blogs

I'm making a blog in which the home page shows all the blog posts each linking to the post's separate page. I am using sinatra as the framework and mongo as the backend. The url's that I generate are something like this:

`http://blogera.io/prakhar/post/4fb8c0562767621088000002/hello-world`

The long number being the ObjectID of the post as stored in mongo. On reaching the url I'll extract the object id, query the db and display the post. Is there a better way to do this? The url's dont look very good and it might be bad for SEO as well?

Any thoughts / suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a number as identifier, not MongoDB's internal _id value of a document. That would make your URLs a lot cleaner, such as:

```
http://blogera.io/prakhar/post/1/hello-world
```

In this case, you would query MongoDB for the blog post with that numerical identifier.

It's also better in case you decide to change database in the future. You rarely wish to change the structure of your URLs. If you do, you would have these long identifiers in your URLs that just stem from your use of MongoDB in the past. That just doesn't make sense.